# Wien's Displacement Law and the Planck Function

Tags: mathematical-physics, maxima-minima, computational-mathematics, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to use an algorithm to find the wavelength maxima of the Planck function for a temperature T in Fortran 90. I used the golden selection search method to find the maximum wavelength of the Planck function for a given T, and compared it to Wien's displacement law. Here's the Planck function in terms of wavelength:

[image]

and here's a screenshot of my output:

[image]

Now, I know that my maxima finding search method is correct, since apparently according to this exercise, my Planck function, which is: `intensity = (2.0d0*h*nu**(3.0d0))/c**(2.0d0) * 1d0 / (EXP((h*nu)/(k*T))-1d0)`

will end up never agreeing with Wien's displacement law on the maximum wavelength. However, I am instead prompted to multiply use a new "modified" Planck function $B_{\nu,2}(T) = \nu^2 B_{\nu}(T)$ which then agreed with the Wien displacement law maximum wavelength with any temperature for up to seven digits or more.

Why is this now complying?

Answer (score 1):

Wien's displacement law is in terms of frequency instead of wavelength. The Planck function has a shape that is dependent on the parametrization you use. In other words, [the maxima will not be the same according to which parametrization you use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law#Maxima_differ_according_to_parameterization).

EDIT: The quantity you study is itself a derivative w.r.t. either $\lambda$, either $\nu$. [$B$ is a spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Correspondence_between_spectral_variable_forms). But that means the spectral densities are connected by

$$B_{\lambda} = \frac{d\nu}{d\lambda} B_{\nu}$$

Since $\lambda\nu=c$, the scaling factor is exactly $\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}=-\frac{\nu^2}{c}$. Note on the wikipedia page they add an extra $-$ sign, I suppose that's to keep the densities positive.

Comment: Why does $/nu^2 B_{nu}(T)$ seem to rectify this?

Comment: I mean to write $\nu^2 B_{\nu}(T)$

Comment: See my edit for further details.